How can I efficiently find if an array contains duplicates within a specific distance using Python?
I'm working on a Python problem where I need to check if an unsorted array contains any duplicates within a specified distance k. Specifically, I need to return True if any value appears more than once within k indices apart, otherwise return False.
For example, given an array [1, 2, 3, 1] and k = 3, the expected output is True because the element 1 appears again within the 3-index range. If k was 2, the expected output would be False.
I know there are multiple ways to approach this, but I want an efficient solution.
How can I solve this problem using a sliding window or another optimal approach?
Constraints:
The array can have up to 10^5 elements.
k is always smaller than the length of the array.
Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
I expected that the sliding window approach would efficiently identify duplicates within the specified distance, with a time complexity of

(

)
O(n), where

n is the size of the array. The set would track the current window elements, and duplicates would be detected within the allowed range.

You mention a sliding window approach but you don't provide any code. Please [edit] and show a [mre].

Sure, sliding window will work. You seem to answer the question (in the title of your post) yourself. What is holding you back?

You can use sliding window and a hash set. Initialise an empty set of values seen. Iterate through each element in the array and check if the current element exists in seen, maintain the sliding window. If not seen then add to seen. Return false if no duplicates found.
def contains_nearby_duplicate(nums, k):
    if len(nums) <= k:  # When n <= k
        return len(set(nums)) < len(nums)
    # Otherwise, continue with sliding window logic
    seen = set()
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        if num in seen:
            return True
        seen.add(num)
        if len(seen) > k:
            seen.remove(nums[i - k])
    return False

Time Complexity: O(n)
Space Complexity: O(min(n, k)) where k is the window size.

@4386427 In practice it would be odd to define k larger than n. However, it is totally possible and valid to define k as larger than n, it's just that if k is equal or larger than n then the question just reduces to duplicates without a range. So the min(n, k) just accounts for these odd cases.

The in operator for a set has average time complexity O(1) but worst-case time complexity of O(n) so your time complexity should be an average of O(n) but a worst-case of O(nk).

(For n <= k, return len(set(nums)) < len(nums).)

@greybeard nice addition

You'd probably get better performance if you used a deque(maxlen=k) instead of a set(). A deque is much cheaper to maintain than a set, and this offsets any performance gain that the set has over deque for membership tests.

@Dunes That's not true and I don't understand how you can think that.

@4386427 LeetCode's version for example doesn't guarantee that.

@nocomment For small k it holds true. A deque is four times faster than a set when k=2. The break even point seems to be k=20 on my machine. But given k can be up to 9999, you're right, it's not a good general purpose answer.

@Dunes 99999 actually. At LeetCode it might btw be just fast enough. Mine under MT0's answer got accepted in 9.5 seconds (theirs exceeded the limit, which seems to be 10 seconds). While the set/dict solutions take ~20 ms.

Slightly different from Euan's approach but basically the same thinking:
def has_duplicates(array, windowsize):
    window = set(array[:windowsize])
    if len(window) < min(windowsize, len(array)):
        return True
    for oldval, newval in zip(array, array[windowsize:]):
        window.remove(oldval)
        if newval in window:
            return True
        window.add(newval)
    return False


You can compare each item with all previous items within the given distance:
def has_duplicate_in_window(array, distance):
    for i in range(1, len(array)):
        value = array[i]
        if any(value == array[j] for j in range(max(i-distance, 0), i)):
            return True
    return False

print(has_duplicate_in_window([1, 2, 3, 1], 3))  # True
print(has_duplicate_in_window([1, 2, 3, 1], 2))  # False

This has time-complexity of O(nk) and has space complexity of O(1).

Likely it would be faster to let the list do the search.

The question appears to be asking for an efficient approach, which brute force rarely is.
